# My own php CMS: setting up a folder structure similar to wordpress and hiding it to the public

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, content-management-system

I can still be considered 'new' to web development and server-side programming especially. I thought building myself a nice, clean and easy to expand CMS would help me improving my skills and my overall comprehension.

At my first try I didnt really gave a thought on how to structure the CMS and just started coding my desired functionality. But then I came to the point where I started wondering if the way I am doing this, is really the way to go. I felt like my backend was too strongly tied together with the 'public visible' website itself (a website for a friendly photographer btw). I started looking around, how other cms' are doing this and decided I will try to build my structure similar to the one of **wordpress**.

So far I setup the following folder structure (which is pretty much the same in wordpress only with other directory names):

- CMS

  - admin - *where the websites maintenance is done*
  - includes - *the core classes/functions for the cms*
  - public - *the public part of the website, similar to a wordpress theme*

My domain, e.g. myurl.com is pointing to the root-folder 'CMS'.

Ok so far so simple. But now I am stuck. If I - as an anonymous visitor - want to get to the public part of the website, I need to call something like: `www.myurl.com/public/whatever.php`

But I - as a website administrator - don't want anyone to be able to see the structure of my site. They should just need to call `myurl.com` and should be automatically redirected to the public folder of my cms. My first thought was, well then I just need to let myurl.com point to the public folder of my cms. But with that solution, how am I - as an administrator - going to reach the admin folder? I would have to setup a new subdomain e.g. admin.myurl.com and let it point to the admin folder.

But... thats not what wordpress is doing. For a wordpress blog the url just needs to point to the root folder and the admin panel can be reached through somewpblog.com/wp-admin

1. can anyone explain to me how this stuff is working in wordpress and what I need to do to achieve this effect for my cms?
2. how can I hide the filename from the url like its done in wordpress, e.g. instead of `somewpblog.com/category.php?id=123` -> `somewpblog.com/?cat=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Front Controller Pattern,  everything else will fall into place : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Basically you need 1 file in your `/public` called `index.php` which will look at the requested URL and do all the including of the rest of your pages.

You can also rewrite the URL via `.htaccess`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I found another Question here on stackoverflow which sums it all up (It has nothing to do with wordpress though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework